# Calculating a Star Rating - Alternative to ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an array of objects that all contain a `star_rating` property

```
[{ name: 'Chemistry', star_rating: 3 },
 { name: 'Physics', star_rating: 5 }]
```

I am displaying these objects in a list via `ng-repeat`. What I want to do is display an object's # of stars alongside the maximum # of stars `(5)`, so the list will look something like this

```
Chemistry [*][*][*][ ][ ]
Physics   [*][*][*][*][*]
```

I have an existing solution that calculates and displays this

```
<i ng-repeat="i in [].constructor(topic.star_rating) track by $index" class="yellow"></i>
<i ng-repeat="i in [].constructor(5 - topic.star_rating) track by $index" class="grey"></i>
```

This works fine for small arrays, but there is a performance hit when the list grows (UI lags & becomes jittery) as these repeats are multiplied by the # of objects

Is there a more performant solution to my current method?

Thanks for any input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your five options as below. I am showing only two for demonstration purpose.

```
<div ng-if="topic.star_rating === 1">
<i class="yellow"></i>
<i class="grey"></i>
<i class="grey"></i>
<i class="grey"></i>
<i class="grey"></i>
</div>

<div ng-if="topic.star_rating === 2">
<i class="yellow"></i>
<i class="yellow"></i>
<i class="grey"></i>
<i class="grey"></i>
<i class="grey"></i>
</div>
```

This should fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! This is indeed a simple solution but it seems like a lot of duplicate code. Plus this is adding 5 `ng-if` checks for every object returned in the list, not sure if that would be optimal?

Comment: Duplicate code contains only static html and this will obviously be a lot faster than using ng-repeat each time. Also, ng-if will remove the "not-required" elements from DOM. Give it a try in your problem, should work.

Comment: You've got a point! It just might be the fastest way since there's no iterations to run, only DOM manipulation.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because it turned out to be the best solution performance wise. No matter the implementation of `ng-repeat` I utilize, it seems to contribute to some lag in the app scrolling through a lengthy list, but your solution (as redundant as it is) offers a smooth scrolling experience, and less scripting!. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

```html
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
   <style>
  .yellow {
  color: #ff0000;
  }
  .grey {
  color: #00ff00;
  }
   </style>
   <body>
  <script>
     var app = angular.module("myShoppingList", []); 
     app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
         $scope.countArr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4];
         $scope.topics = [{ name: 'Chemistry', star_rating: 3 },
      { name: 'Physics', star_rating: 5 }];
     });
  </script>
  <div ng-app="myShoppingList" ng-controller="myCtrl">
     <div ng-repeat="topic in topics">
        <span ng-bind="topic.name" ></span> ->
        <i ng-repeat="i in countArr" ng-class="{'yellow': $index < topic.star_rating, 'grey': $index >= topic.star_rating}">[<span ng-if="$index < topic.star_rating" >*</span>]</i>
     </div>
  </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks @Bhuwan, I can combine your approach with my constructor method and it removes the need to define `countArr` in the controller. `<i ng-repeat="i in [].constructor(5) track by $index"`